# Recovering from a 'corrupt' theme installation on Debian

Tags: debian, themes, lock-screen

I recently installed a new theme on my Debian Stretch machine, however after rebooting, I am unable to get past the login screen. If I enter the incorrect log in details, the systems tells me that the wrong credentials were provided, however if I enter the correct details, nothing happens for a few seconds, then the screen flashes black then goes back to the login screen.

Theme in question: [Flat Remix Gnome](https://github.com/daniruiz/flat-remix-gnome)

I followed the `terminal installation` instructions, and everything seemed to be fine until after a reboot.

I can still login view terminal (switching to a terminal session when I hit the login screen), however I do not know how I can remove this theme and get back to the default one, which will hopefully allow me to log in via the gnome login screen.

Any suggestions?

I've looked at [how to change theme from terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323060/change-gtk-theme-from-command-line?newreg=a63842777a7a4115803117dd24c07a2b) however my `settings.ini` file only very little information in it, and does not contain what the answer suggests.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little strange and desperate, but you can remove all of your personal configurations - themes, browser history, e-mails... - if you remove all files that starts with a dot in your home folder:

```
rm -rf .*
```

**Please, note that DOT**

If you want to keep, for example, your browser history, and you uses Firefox, just rename the folder:

```
mv .mozilla mozilla
```

And back with the original name when you done.